# Why does the spin check while(condition){} not avoid the std::condition_variable::wait(lock, condition)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable, spin

I try to build a fair lock among threads. Each thread runs a `for` loop to do `++iCounter`. Each thread can do `++iCounter` one time, then issue `cv.notify_one()` to wake up another thread using `cv.wait(ul, lambda{check condition_A})` to wait the lock.

I use a `while(condition_A){}` spin in front of the `cv.wait(ul, lambda{check condition_A})` to  avoid the thread wake up itself and get the lock again. The `condition_A` is `iThrID == atom_prev_iThrID && atom_activeThr_counter != 1`.

In order to double check, so I put a `cv.wait(ul, lambda{check condition_A})` to check the `condition_A` again. If it happens in the `cv.wait()`, then print out the message.

In theory, `while(condition_A){}` should filter the case, so `cv.wait(ul, lambda{check condition_A})` should not be triggered. However, it does be triggered and printed out the message. The message is showed as follows.

Why does the spin check `while(condition_A){}` not avoid the `cv.wait(ul, lambda{check condition_A})` to receive the cv.notify_one()?

The example code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <condition_variable>


std::mutex mtx_counter;
std::condition_variable cv;

const int numOfThr {1000};
const int numOfForLoop {100};

std::atomic<int> atom_prev_iThrID {-1};
std::atomic<int> atom_activeThr_counter {0};


std::atomic<int> atom_iCounter{0};
int iCounter {0};


void thrf_fairLock ( const int iThrID )
{
    ++atom_activeThr_counter;

    for ( int i = 0; i < numOfForLoop; ++i )
    {
        //Check condition_A
        //If iThrID thread is the previous user and not the last thread,
        //it will spin to avoid to unique_lock(mtx)
        //till another thread unique_lock(mtx) and assigned atom_prev_iThrID.

        while ( iThrID == atom_prev_iThrID          //iThrID thread is the previous user
                && atom_activeThr_counter != 1 )    // iThrID is the last thread
        {} //spin

        std::unique_lock ul ( mtx_counter );
        cv.wait ( ul, [&]()
        {
            //Using lambda function to check the condition_A in cv.wait() again.
            //This condition_A should not happen,
            //because the previous spin has already checked the same condition.

            bool b { ( iThrID == atom_prev_iThrID     //iThrID thread is the previous user
             && atom_activeThr_counter != 1 )}; // iThrID is the last thread

            if ( b )
            {
                //I am the previous user, so I have to notify another thread to lock.
                cv.notify_one();

                //If condition_A happens, print out the message.
                //Although it should not happen.
                std::cout << iThrID << " : "
                          << atom_prev_iThrID << " : "
                          << atom_activeThr_counter << " |\n";
            }

            return !b;
        } );

        //got critical zone
        ++iCounter;
        ++atom_iCounter;

        atom_prev_iThrID = iThrID;

        ul.unlock();

        //released critical zone
        cv.notify_one();

    }

    --atom_activeThr_counter;
}



int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start testing fair lock ..." << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "print out message in cv.wait(): \n";

    std::vector<std::jthread> thrf_fairLockVec ( numOfThr );

    for ( int iThrID = 0; iThrID < numOfThr; ++iThrID )
    {
        thrf_fairLockVec[iThrID] = std::jthread ( thrf_fairLock, iThrID );
    }

    for ( auto& thr : thrf_fairLockVec )
    {
        if ( thr.joinable() )
            thr.join();
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "numOfThr * numOfForLoop: " << numOfThr* numOfForLoop << "\n";

    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "iCounter: \t" << iCounter << "\n";
    std::cout << "atom_iCounter: \t" << atom_iCounter << "\n";

    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "Test is done." << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Start testing fair lock ...

print out message in cv.wait():
343 : 343 : 13 |
422 : 422 : 14 |
538 : 538 : 11 |
699 : 699 : 13 |
843 : 843 : 11 |


numOfThr * numOfForLoop: 100000

iCounter:       100000
atom_iCounter:  100000


Test is done.
```

Comment: what is supposed to be protected by you lock; what kind of condition on this variable is supposed to be waited for? what do you expect from the atomics everywhere?

Comment: Between exit from the while loop and unique_lock `atom_prev_iThrID ` in the `condition_A`  can be changed.

Comment: @OznOg iCounter is int instead of atomic<int>. The key is to protect ++iCounter.

Comment: @ 273K Wow, this is a good point. Do you mean that the memory reordering problem by compiler optimization and CPU optimization? If it is the key, can I put a fence to avoid the memory reordering? 
I put this fence between the spin and cv.wait(), but it doesn't work.
```std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);```

Comment: Not a memory reordering, it is just a usual data race.

Comment: @ 273K I though about the data race, but I don't understand the reason. For example, there 3 threads, A, B, and C.  Thead_A can only set ```atom_prev_iThrID```  as ```iThrID_A``` by itself after it enter the lock. Thread_B can ony set ```atom_prev_iThrID``` as ```iThrID_B``` instead of ```iThrID_A```, so even with data race, ```atom_prev_iThrID``` can't be changed from ```iThrID_A``` to ```iThrID_B``` then back to ```iThrID_A``` again without thread_A participating in it. ```atom_prev_iThrID```  can only be set as ```iThrID_B``` or ```iThrID_C``` between thread_B and thread_C.

Comment: @ 273K I have a guess. I am thinking about `atom_prev_iThrID`.  `atom_prev_iThrID` is modified in the lock. If we want to read `atom_prev_iThrID` correctly, we should use lock, too. However, the while spin is not in a lock, so it is possible to get a wrong `atom_prev_iThrID`, even `atom_prev_iThrID` is atomic. My idea is from [here](https://youtu.be/F6Ipn7gCOsY?t=1339).

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. The condition_A is `iThrID == atom_prev_iThrID && atom_activeThr_counter != 1`, and the key point here is `atom_activeThr_counter != 1` instead of `iThrID == atom_prev_iThrID`. Those threads are not kick-off at the same time. They kick-off sequentially. The for loop is only run 100 times. It is so short that sometimes all active threads have done the job and leave, so the `atom_activeThr_counter == 1` at the moment. When the while spin saw `atom_activeThr_counter == 1`, it stop spin. When it move to next `cv.wait()`, more threads are loaded in, and `atom_activeThr_counter != 1`, so `cv.wait()` suffers  `atom_activeThr_counter != 1` again.

In order to prove this assumption, I put `barrier_fairLock.arrive_and_wait();` in front of each threads to let thread kick off together, and `cv.wait()` stop suffering `atom_activeThr_counter != 1`.

By the way, let me share my core design idea here. In my experimentation, I noticed that `cv.notify_one()` is very easily wake up the original thread, so the `cv.wait()` have to process the wake up, issues another `cv.notify_one()` and go back to wait. This procedure seems take some time. In order to avoid this situation, so I put a while spin to inspect the condition_A. On my system the only `cv.wait()` version runs 23 seconds, and `while spin + cv.wait()` version can runs 8~10 seconds.

`while spin + cv.wait()` version example code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <barrier>


std::mutex mtx_counter;
std::condition_variable cv;

const int numOfThr {10000};
const int numOfForLoop {100};

std::atomic<int> atom_prev_iThrID {-1};
std::atomic<int> atom_activeThr_counter {0};


std::atomic<int> atom_iCounter{0};
int iCounter {0};

std::barrier barrier_fairLock ( numOfThr, [] {std::cout << "Barrier open. Go go go!!!\n";} );

void thrf_fairLock ( const int iThrID )
{
    barrier_fairLock.arrive_and_wait();
    ++atom_activeThr_counter;

    for ( int i = 0; i < numOfForLoop; ++i )
    {
        //Check condition_A
        //If iThrID thread is the previous user and not the last thread,
        //it will spin to avoid to unique_lock(mtx)
        //till another thread unique_lock(mtx) and assigned atom_prev_iThrID.

        while ( iThrID == atom_prev_iThrID          //iThrID thread is the previous user
                && atom_activeThr_counter != 1 )    // iThrID is the last thread
        {}//spin

        std::unique_lock ul ( mtx_counter );
        cv.wait ( ul, [&]()
        {
            //Using lambda function to check the condition_A in cv.wait() again.
            //This condition_A should not happen,
            //because the previous spin has already checked the same condition.

            bool b { ( iThrID == atom_prev_iThrID     //iThrID thread is the previous user
                       && atom_activeThr_counter != 1 )}; // iThrID is the last thread

            if ( b )
            {
                //I am the previous user, so I have to notify another thread to lock.
                cv.notify_one();

                //If condition_A happens, print out the message.
                //Although it should not happen.
//              std::cout << iThrID << " : "
//                        << atom_prev_iThrID << " : "
//                        << atom_activeThr_counter << " |\n";
            }

            return !b;
        } );

        //got critical zone
        ++iCounter;
        ++atom_iCounter;

        atom_prev_iThrID = iThrID;

        ul.unlock();

        //released critical zone
        cv.notify_one();

    }

    --atom_activeThr_counter;
}



int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start testing fair lock ..." << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "print out message in cv.wait(): \n";

    std::vector<std::jthread> thrf_fairLockVec ( numOfThr );

    for ( int iThrID = 0; iThrID < numOfThr; ++iThrID )
    {
        thrf_fairLockVec[iThrID] = std::jthread ( thrf_fairLock, iThrID );
    }

    for ( auto& thr : thrf_fairLockVec )
    {
        if ( thr.joinable() )
            thr.join();
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "numOfThr * numOfForLoop: " << numOfThr* numOfForLoop << "\n";

    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "iCounter: \t" << iCounter << "\n";
    std::cout << "atom_iCounter: \t" << atom_iCounter << "\n";

    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "Test is done." << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

`while spin + cv.wait()` version result:

```
Start testing fair lock ...

print out message in cv.wait():
Barrier open. Go go go!!!


numOfThr * numOfForLoop: 1000000

iCounter:       1000000
atom_iCounter:  1000000


Test is done.

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 8.123 s
```

`cv.wait()` version example code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <barrier>


std::mutex mtx_counter;
std::condition_variable cv;

const int numOfThr {10000};
const int numOfForLoop {100};

std::atomic<int> atom_prev_iThrID {-1};
std::atomic<int> atom_activeThr_counter {0};


std::atomic<int> atom_iCounter{0};
int iCounter {0};

std::barrier barrier_fairLock ( numOfThr, [] {std::cout << "Barrier open. Go go go!!!\n";} );

void thrf_fairLock ( const int iThrID )
{
    barrier_fairLock.arrive_and_wait();
    ++atom_activeThr_counter;

    for ( int i = 0; i < numOfForLoop; ++i )
    {
        //Check condition_A
        //If iThrID thread is the previous user and not the last thread,
        //it will spin to avoid to unique_lock(mtx)
        //till another thread unique_lock(mtx) and assigned atom_prev_iThrID.

//      while ( iThrID == atom_prev_iThrID          //iThrID thread is the previous user
//              && atom_activeThr_counter != 1 )    // iThrID is the last thread
//      {
////          std::this_thread::yield();
//      }//spin

        std::unique_lock ul ( mtx_counter );
        cv.wait ( ul, [&]()
        {
            //Using lambda function to check the condition_A in cv.wait() again.
            //This condition_A should not happen,
            //because the previous spin has already checked the same condition.

            bool b { ( iThrID == atom_prev_iThrID     //iThrID thread is the previous user
                       && atom_activeThr_counter != 1 )}; // iThrID is the last thread

            if ( b )
            {
                //I am the previous user, so I have to notify another thread to lock.
                cv.notify_one();

                //If condition_A happens, print out the message.
                //Although it should not happen.
//              std::cout << iThrID << " : "
//                        << atom_prev_iThrID << " : "
//                        << atom_activeThr_counter << " |\n";
            }

            return !b;
        } );

        //got critical zone
        ++iCounter;
        ++atom_iCounter;

        atom_prev_iThrID = iThrID;

        ul.unlock();

        //released critical zone
        cv.notify_one();

    }

    --atom_activeThr_counter;
}



int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start testing fair lock ..." << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "print out message in cv.wait(): \n";

    std::vector<std::jthread> thrf_fairLockVec ( numOfThr );

    for ( int iThrID = 0; iThrID < numOfThr; ++iThrID )
    {
        thrf_fairLockVec[iThrID] = std::jthread ( thrf_fairLock, iThrID );
    }

    for ( auto& thr : thrf_fairLockVec )
    {
        if ( thr.joinable() )
            thr.join();
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "numOfThr * numOfForLoop: " << numOfThr* numOfForLoop << "\n";

    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "iCounter: \t" << iCounter << "\n";
    std::cout << "atom_iCounter: \t" << atom_iCounter << "\n";

    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "Test is done." << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

`cv.wait()` version results:

```
Start testing fair lock ...

print out message in cv.wait():
Barrier open. Go go go!!!


numOfThr * numOfForLoop: 1000000

iCounter:       1000000
atom_iCounter:  1000000


Test is done.

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 24.013 s
```

In advance, I noticed that the `cv.notify_one()` may be dropped in some reason. I guess that it is dropped because `cv.notify_one()` arrived earilier than `cv.wait()` in another thread. At this moment, there is no threads are in the `cv.wait()` state. In order to avoid this situation, I use `cv.wait_for(100ms)` to replace `cv.wait()` with `while spin` as `while spin + cv.wait_for(100ms)` version. As following result, it improves the execution time of `while spin + cv.wait()` from 8~10 seconds to 2.5~3.5 seconds.

`while spin + cv.wait_for(100ms)` version example code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <barrier>
#include <numeric>


using namespace std::literals;

std::mutex mtx_counter;
std::condition_variable cv;

const int numOfThr {10000};
const int numOfForLoop {100};

std::atomic<int> atom_prev_iThrID {-1};
std::atomic<int> atom_activeThr_counter {0};


std::atomic<int> atom_iCounter{0};
int iCounter {0};

std::barrier barrier_fairLock ( numOfThr, [] {std::cout << "Barrier open. Go go go!!!\n";} );

void thrf_fairLock ( const int iThrID )
{
    barrier_fairLock.arrive_and_wait();
    ++atom_activeThr_counter;

    for ( int i = 0; i < numOfForLoop; ++i )
    {
//      //Check condition_A
//      //If iThrID thread is the previous user and not the last thread,
//      //it will spin to avoid to unique_lock(mtx)
//      //till another thread unique_lock(mtx) and assigned atom_prev_iThrID.


        while ( iThrID == atom_prev_iThrID          //iThrID thread is the previous user
                && atom_activeThr_counter != 1 )    // iThrID is the last thread
        {
          std::this_thread::yield();

        }//spin


        std::unique_lock ul ( mtx_counter );
        
        //use cv.wait_for to avoid the cv.notify_one() arrived earilier than cv.wait(),
        //so the incoming cv.wait() have to wait longer.
        cv.wait_for ( ul, 100ms, [&]()      
//        cv.wait ( ul, [&]()
        {
            //Using lambda function to check the condition_A in cv.wait() again.
            //This condition_A should not happen,
            //because the previous spin has already checked the same condition.

            bool b { ( iThrID == atom_prev_iThrID     //iThrID thread is the previous user
                       && atom_activeThr_counter != 1 )}; // iThrID is the last thread

            if ( b )
            {
                //I am the previous user, so I have to notify another thread to lock.
                cv.notify_one();

                //If condition_A happens, print out the message.
                //Although it should not happen.

                std::cout << iThrID << " : "
                          << atom_prev_iThrID << " : "
                          << atom_activeThr_counter << " |\n";
            }

            return !b;
        } );

        //got critical zone
        atom_prev_iThrID = iThrID;

        ++iCounter;

        ++atom_iCounter;

        ul.unlock();

        //released critical zone
        cv.notify_one();

    }

    --atom_activeThr_counter;

}


int main()
{

    std::cout << "Start testing fair lock ..." << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "print out message in cv.wait(): \n";

    std::vector<std::jthread> thrf_fairLockVec ( numOfThr );

    for ( int iThrID = 0; iThrID < numOfThr; ++iThrID )
    {
        thrf_fairLockVec[iThrID] = std::jthread ( thrf_fairLock, iThrID );
    }

    for ( auto& thr : thrf_fairLockVec )
    {
        if ( thr.joinable() )
            thr.join();
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "numOfThr * numOfForLoop: " << numOfThr* numOfForLoop << "\n";

    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "iCounter: \t" << iCounter << "\n";
    std::cout << "atom_iCounter: \t" << atom_iCounter << "\n";

    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "Test is done." << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

`while spin + cv.wait_for(100ms)` version result is as follows:

```
Start testing fair lock ...

print out message in cv.wait():
Barrier open. Go go go!!!


numOfThr * numOfForLoop: 1000000

iCounter:       1000000
atom_iCounter:  1000000


Test is done.

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 2.688 s
```